# While I have 3 Tabs, tabLayout.getChildCount() returns 1

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have added 3 tabs to ViewPager and then used setupWithViewPager to create tabs accordingly:

```
private void setupFragments(){
    ViewPager mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new SignalsFragment(),"Live Signals");
    adapter.addFragment(new FavSignalsFragment(),"Fav Signals");
    adapter.addFragment(new RemotesFragment(),"Remotes");
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    System.out.println("Number Of Tabs: "+tabLayout.getChildCount());
}
```

And it returns 1
I need to etherate through tabs to set onLongClickListener for them...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add your layout

Comment: Thanks, But I found the solution and posted it. Since in <TabLayout> there is nothing special, It had nothing to do with it. It was just the matter of understanding structure of children that ViewPager sets the TabLayout up...

Answer (score 1):

Here I found the issue and solution:
I was mistaking the direct child of TabLayout with tabs, while there is just one direct child of TabLayout object and it is group of tabs. So the key is to first extract the group and etherate trough its children.
Here is the code that worked for me:

```
private void setupFragments(){
    ViewPager mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new 
    SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new SignalsFragment(),"Live Signals");
    adapter.addFragment(new FavSignalsFragment(),"Fav Signals");
    adapter.addFragment(new RemotesFragment(),"Remotes");
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    View tabLayoutChild = tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) tabLayoutChild;
    group.getChildAt(0).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```